# How to reuse an existing browser session in another webdriver instance

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

As the question says - is it possible to use a single browser instance across multiple examples(i.e across different browser sessions)?

Scenario: While running a bunch selenium tests, if the code stops for some reason one will restart the code and the whole process begins again. Instead, if the session can be reused (even after the program that initialized it had closed.), then I can start the tests from where I stopped !!!

Comment: Yes, but then you lose the advantage of starting with a clean environment and a known state, i.e. you're introducing unpredictability to save time. Better to focus on smaller, self-contained tests, and getting them reliable enough that they don't need to stop / be stopped.

Comment: @AndrewRegan, you are right and I'm aware of what you said. I'm not interested in having a clean environment for each case. For e.g I sign in to mail and test 'opening mails' and in the next test I'm interested in testing un-spamming mails for which I surely do not want to sign in again.

Comment: The other issue is speed of course. I don't care about clean environment but I spend 20 minutes opening browsers and 20 minutes running tests. So why I can't just reuse a browser instance if it suits me?

Comment: @AndrewRegan how it can be done?